# $.post - array from javascript to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this array in javascript:

```
arr = [1, "string", 3]
```

And this, my ajax call:

```
$.post("./ajax_book_client.php",
        {'client_info[]': arr},
    function(data) {
          // some stuffs here
        }
});
```

Here's the php excerpt:

```
<?php 
    $arr = $_POST['client_info'];

    // I want to access the array, indexed, like this:
    $arr[0] = 2;
    $arr[1] = "Hello";
    $arr[2] = 10000;

?>
```

But I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2

What's the correct way to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Remove `}` from `});` to remove syntax error.

Also no need to use `[]` with `client_info` so you can remove it.

Use:

```
<script>
var arr = [1, "string", 3];
$.post("./ajax_book_client.php",
        {'client_info': arr},
    function(data) {
          // some stuffs here
        }
);
</script>
```

ajax_book_client.php

```
<?php 
    $arr = $_POST['client_info'];

    echo $arr[0];
    echo $arr[1];
    echo $arr[2];
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

extra braces, change:

```
$.post("./ajax_book_client.php",
        {'client_info[]': arr},
    function(data) {
          // some stuffs here
        }
});
```

to

```
$.post("./ajax_book_client.php",
        {'client_info[]': arr},
    function(data) {
          // some stuffs here
       // } <--remove this
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your JS. Remove one `}`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `client_info[]` to `client_info` and extra brace

Try

```
<script>
var arr = [1, "string", 3];
$.post("./ajax_book_client.php",
    {'client_info': arr},
    function(data) {
      // some stuffs here
    }
);
</script>
```